# Decidability language, intersection

Tags: computability, closure-properties, semi-decidability

I have two langages $ A, B \in \mathrm{coRE}$.  How can I prove that $ A \triangle B= ( A - B) \cup (B - A)$ is also in $\mathrm{coRE}\,$?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? Did you try to produce a Turing machine that enumerates or accepts $\overline{A\triangle B}$, for example?

Answer (score 1):

The language $A = \Sigma^*$ is coRE. Since $A \triangle B = \overline{B}$, the statement you are trying to prove implies RE=coRE, which is known to be false: for example, the set of all programs that halt is in RE but not in coRE.

Comment: What if we restrict $A$ and $B$ to $\mathrm{coRE}\setminus\mathrm{RE}$?

Comment: @Luke Then the statement would still be false, but the counterexample would be more complicated.

Comment: ah, yes I think I can see a counterexample, but it is indeed fiddly.